# Ignore half hour columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like:

```
unix_time  | value
--------------------
1395588600 |   1    (3:30 PM)
1395590400 |   2    (4:00 PM)
1395592200 |   3    (4:30 PM)
1395594000 |   4    (5:00 PM)
```

How can I get the results that are only at hour marks (4PM and 5PM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `unix_time` to a date using [`from_unixtime()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and then extract the [`minute()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute).

```
SELECT unix_time, value 
FROM `time_table` 
WHERE minute(from_unixtime(unix_time)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need a query of the form

```
 WHERE time_to_previous_hour(unix_time) = unix_time
```

Here's how to do that.

```
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_time), '%H:00') =
       DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_time), '%H:%i')
```

See this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/644d6/4/0

This works too

```
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') = 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_time)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/644d6/5/0

Comment: If you use minute() you can make 2 function calls instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select
    t.unix_time,
    t.value
from
    tbl t
where
    hour(from_unixtime(t.unix_time)) in (4, 5)
    and minute(from_unixtime(t.unix_time)) = 0
```